# Sending POST to API with httr for each item in list

Tags: r, loops, httr

I have a list of symbols that I would like to place orders through an API with.

```
toorder<-list("AAPL","CBS","NVDA","STZ")
```

When I use:

```
for (i in toorder)
{
POST("https://paper-api.alpaca.markets/v1/orders",body = list("symbol" = paste0('"', i, '"',sep=""), "qty" = 1, "side" = "buy", "type" = "market", "time_in_force" = "day"), encode = "json",
             add_headers("APCA-API-KEY-ID" = "mykeyishere"),
add_headers("APCA-API-SECRET-KEY" = "mysecretkeyishere"),
accept_json()
             )}
```

No orders are placed.  However,

```
POST("https://paper-api.alpaca.markets/v1/orders",body = list("symbol" = "AAPL", "qty" = 1, "side" = "buy", "type" = "market", "time_in_force" = "day"), encode = "json",
             add_headers("APCA-API-KEY-ID" = "mykeyisenteredhere"),
add_headers("APCA-API-SECRET-KEY" = "mysecretkeyisenteredhere"),
accept_json()
             )
```

works just fine.

What is the best way for me to produce code that will POST once for each symbol in my list?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Consider wrapping your POST call in a function and using `lappy`:

```
PostFunciton <- function (Symbol)
{
  POST("https://paper-api.alpaca.markets/v1/orders",body = list("symbol" = Symbol), "qty" = 1, "side" = "buy", "type" = "market", "time_in_force" = "day"), encode = "json",
       add_headers("APCA-API-KEY-ID" = "mykeyishere"),
       add_headers("APCA-API-SECRET-KEY" = "mysecretkeyishere"),
       accept_json()
  )
}

Results <- lapply(toorder, PostFunciton)
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you.  The API that this connects to rejects the rapid requests, though.  Any idea how to add some delay, with something like Sys.sleep()?

Answer (score 0):

I made a `for`loop with a `Sys.sleep()` aspect to make my code work in situations that my POSTS were too rapid-fire.

The code used is below:

```
for(i in toorder$body){
 POST("https://paper-api.alpaca.markets/v1/orders",body = list("symbol" = i, "qty" = 1, "side" = "buy", "type" = "market", "time_in_force" = "day"), encode = "json",
   add_headers("APCA-API-KEY-ID" = "mykeyishere"),
   add_headers("APCA-API-SECRET-KEY" = "mysecretkeyishere"),
   accept_json()
)
Sys.sleep(time=1)

}
```